# Bridging header to allow for C function use in Swift fails

Tags: c, swift

I am attempting to use a bridging header to allow for a C function from the C standard library to be called from Swift.

My project is a Mac OS X Command Line Application program.  I have added a header file to the project named "Bridging-Header.h".  In this file I have added:

```
#include < stdio.h>
```

I have then gone to the project build settings, to "Swift Compiler - Code Generation" and have added the filename "Bridging-Header.h" to the line labelled "Objective-C Bridging Header".

In my Swift file, I attempt to call printf:

```
import Foundation

var result = printf("Hello")
```

However, the compiler reports that printf is an unresolved identifier.

What am I doing wrong ?  I have a similar workflow using functions from ifaddrs.h with no issues.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<stdio.h>` is already included from `import Foundation`, so you don't
need a bridging header for that.

The actual problem is that

```
int printf(const char * restrict format, ...);
```

takes a *variable argument list*, and therefore is not imported to Swift.
*Fortunately,* there is a corresponding function taking a `va_list`
which is imported to Swift:

```
int vprintf(const char * restrict format, va_list ap);
```

*Unfortunately,* passing a `va_list` in Swift is a bit cumbersome,
in particular for strings.
Examples:

```
vprintf("i=%d, x=%f\n", getVaList([12, 34.56]))
// i=12, x=34.560000
vprintf("status=%s\n", getVaList(["OK".cStringUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)]))
// status=OK
```

Note that for printing to the standard output, you can simply use
`println()` with the `String` formatting methods:

```
println(String(format:"i=%d, x=%f, status=%@", 12, 34.56, "OK"))
// i=12, x=34.560000, status=OK
```

Comment: Hi Martin, thanks for that informative answer.  Just learned that variadic functions are off the Swift import list and that stdio.h is already imported.  You are absolutely right, a native println is superior, but I picked printf thinking it would be an easy example of a C function called via Swift.  Ironically, the BSD networking code I was working with the other day provided a simpler example!